# How does this inheritance work?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

```
const proto = {
  hello () {
    return `Hello, my name is ${ this.name }`;
  }
};
const greeter = (name) => Object.assign(Object.create(proto), { name });
const george = greeter('george');
const msg = george.hello();
console.log(msg);
```

I was reading `JavaScript Scene` when I came across the above type of inheritance. I am new to JS.

So, `proto` is the object we will create a prototype from.

**Que 1: If `proto` is an object, how does it have a function within it self without associating it with a key? Shouldn't it be `{ "hello" : function(){...} }`**

Related to that,
**Que 2: Can fat arrow functions be stored within objects as key-value pairs??**

**Que 3. How does `Object.assign` work?**
After reading MDN, what I understand is that everything from 2nd argument on is copied into the `target`, which in our case is a prototype. Correct?

Comment: **For point 1 & 2**.=> this code snippet belongs to ES2016, and this version of JS, it's valid JavaScript.

Comment: @AshishKumar I know it is valid JS. I am just trying to wrap my head around how it works.

Comment: You missed the part **ES2016**... :)

Comment: `Object.assign` is to extend an object with other objects. It copies the properties of other objects to the current one.

Comment: #3: `Object.create(proto)` creates an object whose [[Prototype]] hidden link points to proto thus `proto` is not modified, instead `name` is added to this new object

Comment: #2: it's actually a very useful feature of es6, allowing you to bind the function to the context of the object not of the caller. E.g: I use it a lot with React which otherwise binds the method calls to the calling component

Comment: The title in the question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the questions you are asking in the post. Also, there are too many questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Que 1: If proto is an object, how does it have a function within it self without associating it with a key? Shouldn't it be { "hello" : function(){...} }

This is because of the enw ES6 syntax of defining methods on an object. Refer this for details on the syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

> Que 2: Can fat arrow functions be stored within objects as key-value pairs?

Yes. You can do it like below:

```
let obj = {
  func: () => {
    console.log(`Hello world!`);
  }
}

obj.func();
```

> Que 3. How does Object.assign work?

From the docs:

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.
>
> `Object.assign(target, ...sources)`

In your case its actually not prototype but an object which is prototypally-linked to `proto`. So your `greeter` returns an object which has `name` and the `hello()` method is from the prototype chain

Comment: Okay, my reason behind asking `Que 1.` is this: I know functions can be stored in variables. The way the code snippet is written, I was confused whether `ES6` classes can also be stored into variables by skipping the `class` keyword. Looks like that might be the case?

Comment: The syntax `hello () {}` in `Que 1` is just a compact version for `{ "hello" : function(){...} }`. Refer this: http://www.2ality.com/2014/12/es6-oop.html

Comment: @LittleChild: No. But you can use class expressions such as `var foo = class {};` (similar to function expression).